# D3js v5 tree draggable

Tags: d3.js

I want to create drag tree using D3js V5.
But when I choose dragging start it jump to other coordinate.

How can I fix this?

```
var dragStartX = null,
        dragStartY = null;
    var svg = d3.select($container).append("svg")
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", function() {
                dragStartX = parseFloat(d3.event.sourceEvent.offsetX);
                dragStartY = parseFloat(d3.event.sourceEvent.offsetY);
                console.log("start", dragStartX, dragStartY);
            })
            .on("drag", function() {
                var g = d3.select(this).selectAll("g.containerG");


                dragStartX += parseFloat(d3.event.dx);
                dragStartY += parseFloat(d3.event.dy);
                g.attr("transform", "translate(" +
                    dragStartX + "," + dragStartY + ")");
            })
            .on("end", function() {
                console.log("end", dragStartX, dragStartY);
                dragStartX = null;
                dragStartY = null;
                console.log("null", dragStartX, dragStartY);
            }))
```

Comment: Why is this site difficult?

http://jsfiddle.net/b4xcg2sj/7/  Here is my full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used d3.zoom for this.

`var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .extent([[margin.left, margin.top], [width, height]])
    .scaleExtent([1, 1])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);`

Then call the zoom on svg selection, and change transform attribute on zoom event.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b4xcg2sj/35/

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Gio-Ghviniashvili Your solution above works beautifully for me.  How would you also add zoom. So you had pan and zoom? Yours is the only working example of d3 v5 I can find and work from. Thank you in advance. This is great!

Comment: Two things that I did:
* changed scaleExtent to scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
* and modified zoomed function.

Comment: @GioGhviniashvili :  Can you please help me with issue in below post. My d3 tree is behaving weird. After 2 clicks on "More..." node , the tree does not behave as expected

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076145/1344006