# Paging for D3 tree child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, hierarchy

I am trying to implement paging in d3 tree. Can anyone please help me with the same.

Please find below my code with screenshots of current and expected output.

The data_tree is the input data variable. This gets read by script below and produces hierarchy tree as showed in screenshot

```js
data_tree = {
  "Type": "Root",
  "id": 0,
  "name": "ERM",
  "ParentDocType": "EnterpriseWide",
  "children": [{
    "Type": "Stem",
    "id": 4,
    "name": "RG",
    "ParentDocType": "EnterpriseWide",
    "children": [{
        "Type": "Stem",
        "id": 5,
        "name": "WCR F",
        "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
        "children": [{
          "Type": "Stem",
          "id": 50,
          "name": "WCR P",
          "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
          "children": [{
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 8,
              "name": "IBQA SD",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 9,
              "name": "WCR EMS",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 28,
              "name": "WCR DD & RGEC",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 29,
              "name": "PMM",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 30,
              "name": "PRRM",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 31,
              "name": "WCR Rep",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 32,
              "name": "RR",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 33,
              "name": "CO",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 34,
              "name": "LD",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 35,
              "name": "ESRM",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 36,
              "name": "TPCR",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 37,
              "name": "InterA",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 38,
              "name": "DR",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 39,
              "name": "MAR",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 40,
              "name": "BSLM",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 51,
              "name": "CCR Meas",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 52,
              "name": "WLP",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 53,
              "name": "TTS Pro",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 54,
              "name": "CI",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 55,
              "name": "LL",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 56,
              "name": "SP",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 57,
              "name": "CC",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 58,
              "name": "CRE",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 59,
              "name": "Sec",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 60,
              "name": "SS",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": [

              ]
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Stem",
        "id": 10,
        "name": "GCMP",
        "ParentDocType": "EnterpriseWide",
        "children": [{
          "Type": "Leaf",
          "id": 11,
          "name": "WCR CMS",
          "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
          "children": [

          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Stem",
        "id": 12,
        "name": "REAVP",
        "ParentDocType": "EnterpriseWide",
        "children": [{
          "Type": "Stem",
          "id": 13,
          "name": "CREAVS",
          "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
          "children": [{
            "Type": "Leaf",
            "id": 14,
            "name": "CREAVP",
            "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
            "children": [

            ]
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var root =JSON.parse(data_tree);

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  rectW = 150,
  rectH = 50;



//var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);

var nodeWidth = 150;
var nodeHeight = 50;
var horizontalSeparationBetweenNodes = 16;
var verticalSeparationBetweenNodes = 128;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .nodeSize([nodeWidth + horizontalSeparationBetweenNodes, nodeHeight + verticalSeparationBetweenNodes])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1.25;
  });


/*var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 6];
});*/

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .target(function(d) {
    var o = d.target;
    o.y = o.y - 50
    return o;
  })
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH];
  });


var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg").attr("width", document.getElementById("body").style.width).attr("height", document.getElementById("body").style.height)
  .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5, 3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 650 + "," + 20 + ")scale(0.7)");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
zm.translate([650, 20]);

root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;

d3.select("#myCheckbox").on("change", enableLink);

enableLink(root);




d3.select("#body").style("height", "800px");



function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      x = text.attr("x"),
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = 0, //parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null)
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("x", x)
      .attr("y", y)
      .attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan")
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
          .text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}



function enableLink(source) {


  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 125;

  });

  // Update the nodes…

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.



  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    }).on("click", click);



  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.ParentDocType == "EnterpriseWide") return "darkblue";
      if (d.ParentDocType == "WholesaleCreditRisk") return "blue";

      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }).call(wrap, rectW - 10);


  nodeEnter
    .append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.url;
    });




  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.ParentDocType == "EnterpriseWide") return "darkblue";
      if (d.ParentDocType == "WholesaleCreditRisk") return "blue";
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
    //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);

  nodeExit.select("text");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      d.y = d.y + 100;
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0 + 100
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y + 100;
  });

}
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {


    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    enableLink(d);
  


}

//Redraw for zoom
function redraw() {
  //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
    " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  fill: white;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.darkblue {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="body" style="border: 1px black solid; width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
</body>
```

**Current output** [image: Current output]

**Expected output**[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var root = {
  "Type": "Root",
  "id": 0,
  "name": "ERM",
  "ParentDocType": "EnterpriseWide",
  "children": [{
    "Type": "Stem",
    "id": 4,
    "name": "RG",
    "ParentDocType": "EnterpriseWide",
    "children": [{
        "Type": "Stem",
        "id": 5,
        "name": "WCR F",
        "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
        "children": [{
          "Type": "Stem",
          "id": 50,
          "name": "WCR P",
          "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
          "children": [{
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 8,
              "name": "IBQA SD",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 9,
              "name": "WCR EMS",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 28,
              "name": "WCR DD & RGEC",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 29,
              "name": "PMM",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 30,
              "name": "PRRM",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 31,
              "name": "WCR Rep",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 32,
              "name": "RR",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 33,
              "name": "CO",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 34,
              "name": "LD",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 35,
              "name": "ESRM",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 36,
              "name": "TPCR",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 37,
              "name": "InterA",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 38,
              "name": "DR",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 39,
              "name": "MAR",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 40,
              "name": "BSLM",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 51,
              "name": "CCR Meas",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 52,
              "name": "WLP",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 53,
              "name": "TTS Pro",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 54,
              "name": "CI",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 55,
              "name": "LL",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 56,
              "name": "SP",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 57,
              "name": "CC",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 58,
              "name": "CRE",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 59,
              "name": "Sec",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "Type": "Leaf",
              "id": 60,
              "name": "SS",
              "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Stem",
        "id": 10,
        "name": "GCMP",
        "ParentDocType": "EnterpriseWide",
        "children": [{
          "Type": "Leaf",
          "id": 11,
          "name": "WCR CMS",
          "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
          "children": []
        }]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Stem",
        "id": 12,
        "name": "REAVP",
        "ParentDocType": "EnterpriseWide",
        "children": [{
          "Type": "Stem",
          "id": 13,
          "name": "CREAVS",
          "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
          "children": [{
            "Type": "Leaf",
            "id": 14,
            "name": "CREAVP",
            "ParentDocType": "WholesaleCreditRisk",
            "children": []
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
};

function pageNodes(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c));
    if (d.children.length > pageNodes.maxNode) {
      d.pages = {}
      const count = pageNodes.maxNode - 1;
      const l = Math.ceil(d.children.length / count);
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        let startRange = i * count;
        let endRange = i * count + count;
        d.pages[i] = d.children.slice(startRange, endRange);
        pageNodes.addNode(d.pages[i], "More...", {
          __next: i != (l - 1) ? i + 1 : 0,
        });
      }
      d.children = d.pages[0];
    }
  }
}

pageNodes.maxNode = 5;

pageNodes.addNode = function(children, name, more) {
  let node = Object.assign({
    Type: "Leaf",
    id: children[children.length - 1].id + 10000,
    ParentDocType: children[children.length - 1].ParentDocType,
    name: name,
  }, more);
  children.push(node);
};

root.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c));

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = window.innerWidth - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  rectW = 150,
  rectH = 50;

// var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);

var nodeWidth = 150;
var nodeHeight = 50;
var horizontalSeparationBetweenNodes = 16;
var verticalSeparationBetweenNodes = 128;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .nodeSize([nodeWidth + horizontalSeparationBetweenNodes, nodeHeight + verticalSeparationBetweenNodes])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1.25;
  });


/*var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 6];
});*/

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .target(function(d) {
    var o = d.target;
    o.y = o.y - 50
    return o;
  })
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH];
  });


var svg = d3.select("#body").append("svg").attr("width", document.getElementById("body").style.width).attr("height", document.getElementById("body").style.height)
  .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5, 3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 650 + "," + 20 + ")scale(0.7)");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
zm.translate([650, 20]);

root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = height / 2;

d3.select("#myCheckbox").on("change", enableLink);

enableLink(root);

d3.select("#body").style("height", "800px");

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      x = text.attr("x"),
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = 0, //parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null)
      .append("tspan")
      .attr("x", x)
      .attr("y", y)
      .attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan")
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y)
          .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
          .text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

function enableLink(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 125;

  });

  // Update the nodes…

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    }).on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.ParentDocType == "EnterpriseWide") return "darkblue";
      if (d.ParentDocType == "WholesaleCreditRisk") return "blue";

      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }).call(wrap, rectW - 10);

  nodeEnter
    .append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
      return d.url;
    });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.ParentDocType == "EnterpriseWide") return "darkblue";
      if (d.ParentDocType == "WholesaleCreditRisk") return "blue";
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
    //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);

  nodeExit.select("text");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      d.y = d.y + 100;
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0 + 100
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y + 100;
  });
}
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.hasOwnProperty('__next')) {
    d.parent.children = d.parent.pages[d.__next];
  } else if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  enableLink(d);
}

//Redraw for zoom
function redraw() {
  //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
    " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  fill: white;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.darkblue {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="body" style="border: 1px black solid; width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
```

Comment: what is logic of adding 10000 to the line children[children.length - 1].id ?

Comment: @CarpeDiem the issue was nodes id was getting duplicated so multiple nodes were having duplicate ids hence were moving incorrect nodes during transition to solve the issue we assigned the more label nodes id greater than 10000+ which would result in unique node ids which solve the incorrect nodes transition issue.

Comment: i did a bit of hit and trial to add id component after your 1st solution in Object.assign. what are all mandatory components need to be taken logically to work it correctly?

Comment: @CarpeDiem when i solved previously the same issue occurred to me but I forgot how did i solve the issue, the structure adjustment and the click change is all logic need to make it work